# Hive UDF which gets parameter as input

Tags: hive, udf

Can we write an Hive UDF which takes 'String-value' as input .
Any example or link will be helpful.
I have visited the below link :
http://blog.matthewrathbone.com/2013/08/10/guide-to-writing-hive-udfs.html

Need some more help.

```
package com.main;

import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDF;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;

public class ReplaceNumber extends UDF {
    private Text result = new Text();

    public Text evaluate(String str) {

        String rep = (str);
        result.set("HELLO:"+rep);
        return result;

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you provide more details , what you meant by 'String-value', You want to pass entire row as String to the UDF or a particular column which is of String type. You can paste your try out code too.

Comment: @abhi Say for example I pass '-1' as a string from my UDF ,so my select query should give me "Hello" with each output and and if nothing is passed it should return only the rows. 

    select testUdf(method) from tests3atable limit 2; 

So how to pass that '-1' to UDF. I have added the code example in the question.

Comment: Do you really need to write an UDF to achieve this; It seems more like a CONCAT logic to be applied on the columns. Also you can use CASE WHEN to handle -1 and call UDF accordingly.

Comment: @Abhi based on "-1" string i have to make 'start_time' and 'end_time' that will be used in select query.
'code'